# Nested child_added event listeners in fire base for web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using child_added child event listener to read specific data and storing them in another node

```
database.ref().child('States').on('child_added',function(snap){
    console.log('reached States'+ count);
    count++;
    distref=snap.child('Districts').ref.on('child_added',function(distsnap){
         console.log('reached dists'+ccount);
         ccount++
         database.ref().child('DistrictNames').push().set({
            districtName : distsnap.val().districtName,
        });


    });  
})
```

1. How do i use off method after both on methods have completed
2. Will distref the variable used to store each reference overwrite itself?
   if so what happens to the previous listeners and how to detach them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to attach a new listener for the districts. Since the data for a district is under a state, all the data is already included in the snapshot you get.

So:

```
database.ref().child('States').on('child_added',function(snap){
    snap.child('Districts').forEach(function(distsnap){
         database.ref('DistrictNames').push({
            districtName : distsnap.val().districtName,
        });
    });  
})
```